# How to reverse a number in java with single variable using recursion?

Tags: java

```
//Is there any simple idea other than it?
static int rev(int n){
    if (n==0)return 0;
    else return n%10^10+rev(n/10)   
}
```

I want to reverse number with single variable and recursion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670444/using-recursion-to-reverse-an-integer-without-the-use-of-strings

Comment: I did see the same answer later on but i was asking reversing a number with single variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Here i got the idea.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Let the number be 139.
    int n=139;
    System.out.println("reverse is "+rev(n));
}
static int rev(int n){
    if (n<10)return n;
    else return n%10*(int) Math.pow(10,(int)Math.log10(n))+rev(n/10);
        //Math class is used to return the number of digits and power.
}
```

This gives:: reverse is 931